# Add part of line found after #solution to file

Tags: python

I have a script that puts the line that starts with #Solution 1 in a new file together with the name of the input file. But I want to add the piece belonging to Major from the input file. Can someone please help me to figure out how to get the piece of text?

The script now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

dr = "/home/nwalraven/Result_pgx/Runfolder/Runres_Aldy" outdr = "/home/nwalraven/Result_pgx/Runfolder/Aldy_res_txt" tag = ".aldy"


for f in os.listdir(dr):
    if f.endswith(tag):
        print(f)
        new_file_name = f.split('_')[0]+'.txt' # get the name of the file before the '_' and add '.txt' to it
        with open(dr+"/"+f) as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                f
                if line.startswith("#Solution 1"):
                    with open(outdr+"/"+new_file_name,"a",newline='\n') as new_file:
                        new_file.write(f.split('.')[0] + "\n")
                        new_file.write(line + "\n")
                if line.startswith("#Solution 2"):
                    with open(outdr+"/"+new_file_name,"a",newline='\n') as new_file:
                        new_file.write(line + "\n")
                        print("Meerdere oplossingen gevonden! Check Aldy bestand" )
```

The input:

file = EMQN3-S3_COMT.aldy

```
#Sample Gene    SolutionID  Major   Minor   Copy    Allele  Location    Type    Coverage    Effect  dbSNP   Code    Status
#Solution 1: *Met, *ValB
EMQN3-S3    COMT    1   *Met/*ValB  Met;ValB    0   Met 19950234    C>T 530 H62=    rs4633  
EMQN3-S3    COMT    1   *Met/*ValB  Met;ValB    0   Met 19951270    G>A 651 V158M   rs4680  
EMQN3-S3    COMT    1   *Met/*ValB  Met;ValB    1   ValB
```

file = EMQN3-S3_CYP2B6.aldy

```
#Sample Gene    SolutionID  Major   Minor   Copy    Allele  Location    Type    Coverage    Effect  dbSNP   Code    Status
#Solution 1: *1.001, *1.001
EMQN3-S3    CYP2B6  1   *1/*1   1.001;1.001 0   1.001                           
EMQN3-S3    CYP2B6  1   *1/*1   1.001;1.001 1   1.001
```

The result it gives right now:

```
EMQN3-S3_COMT.aldy
#Solution 1: *Met, *ValB

EMQN3-S3_CYP2B6.aldy
#Solution 1: *1.001, *1.001
```

The result I need:

```
EMQN3-S3_COMT.aldy
#Solution 1: *Met/*ValB

EMQN3-S3_CYP2B6.aldy
#Solution 1: *1/*1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print out the line, you could use regular expression to replace text before printing the line.
On the other hand, if you know it always starts with a fixed number of chars, then it's easier and faster to edit the line manually.

With regex:

```
# Importing regular expressions
import re

# Setting up regex replacement to replace ", " with "/"
regex = "\, "
replacement = "/"

...

# Format the line before printing it
line_formatted = re.sub(regex, replacement, line)
new_file.write(line.replace(regex, replacement) + "\n")  # edited

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this part of your script:

```
...
if line.startswith("#Solution 1"):
    with open(outdr+"/"+new_file_name,"a",newline='\n') as new_file:
        new_file.write(f.split('.')[0] + "\n")
        solution = "/".join([x.strip().split(".")[0] for x in line.split(",")])
        new_file.write(solution + "\n")
...
```

It will do the following:

- split the string into two tokens, based on the comma
- strip them
- remove the decimal part (if any) from the token
- rejoin the string using the slash.

Hope it helps.